# Ordering by specific field value first with if function on column name

Tags: mysql

I am using an `ORDER BY` function to get the right sorting of my DB output

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ds.status, 'open', 'afgerond', 'in behandeling', 'hold', 'geoffereerd', 'gefactureerd', 'vervallen'), ds.dossier_nr DESC
```

What I would like is when status 'in behandeling' is used in this query that these items are sorted by `ordr.datum_leveren ASC` instead of `ds.dossier_nr`

Is it possible and how to achieve to use an if function in an `ORDER BY` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional sorting criteria that returns the new column when it has that status, and some constant otherwise. The constant doesn't matter, since all those other statuses will be grouped together in this level of the sorting, and then `ds.dossier_nr` will be used to sort them.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ds.status, 'open', 'afgerond', 'in behandeling', 'hold', 'geoffereerd', 'gefactureerd', 'vervallen'), 
    IF(ds.status = 'in behandeling', ordr.datum_leveren, 0) ASC,
    ds.dossier_nr DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior with a `case` expression in the `order by` clause:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ds.status, 'open', 
                          'afgerond', 
                          'in behandeling',
                          'hold',
                          'geoffereerd',
                          'gefactureerd',
                          'vervallen'),
         CASE ds.status WHEN 'in behandeling' THEN ordr.datum_leveren
                        ELSE ds.dossier_nr * -1
         END ASC
```

Comment: Why to use * -1 ?

Comment: @Muiter because I'm using a single term that should sort `asc` on one scenario and `desc` on the other. Since you can't parameterize syntactic elements, you can simulate it by always sorting `asc`, and multiplying by `-1` in the relevant case.